# Различие между volume и partition

Tags: partition

В чём различие между понятиями том диска (volume) и раздела диска (partition)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В принципе, это одно и то же. По крайней мере, если речь идет о стандартных дисках в среде Windows, а не динамических.

Разница скорее такая

- partition - это физическое представление раздела на жестком диске;
- в то время, как volume - то как его видит сама операционная система.

Типичным примером не совпадения этих понятий является т.н. "расширенный раздел" ("extended partition"). Он работает как контейнер для логических разделов. При этом сам он ФС не содержит, т.е. томом ("volume") в классическом понимании не является.